# Keras: Better Way to expand dimensions of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, neural-network

I got an `ìnput_shape=[1, 7, 6, 1]` on my first layer because on each run my batch is 1, the shape of the input array is (7, 6) and I got one channel.
My current solution to expand one 2D numpy array to match this input shape is really ugly:

```py
input_array: np.ndarray = np.array([[ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,], \
       [ -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,], \
       [1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,], \
       [-1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,], \
       [-1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,], \
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,], \
       [ -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,]])
np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(input_array, axis=0), axis=-1), axis=0)
```

How can I expand my array to match the input shape without doing such an atrocity?

Comment: Please tell me if I did something wrong, will correct happily

Comment: Please clarify if *input_array* is a list of lists or a 2D numpy array. Using '\' is redundant. For a 2D array *arr*: `arr[None,...,None]`

Comment: The included code  `(1, 1, 7, 6, 1)` doesn't give the desired shape `[1, 7, 6, 1]`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny the input_array is of type `numpy.ndarray`
if I dont reshape to `(1, 1, 7, 6, 1)` my model.predict() fails with `expected shape=(None, 1, 7, 6, 1), found shape=(None, 7, 6, 1)`.. I guess I got something wrong or misunderstood something, but this works right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.reshape`. If you want the shape `(1, 7, 6, 1)` for example:

```
reshaped_array = np.reshape(input_array, (1, 7, 6, 1))
print(reshaped_array.shape)
(1, 7, 6, 1)
```